# parsing a list and creating columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large list in which I need to identify on Titles and URLs each section in the list may have more information that I'm not concerned with.  The list looks like Column B in the picture.  I'm looking to make it into two columns like E & F.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Could you write us that on what Basis you have connected the Tiles with URL since the group has others too?

Answer (score 0):

The simple/messy way to do this would be:

Paste this formula in column C

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("item",A1)),A1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".com",A1)),A1,""))
```

Then copy paste the result as values into a new sheet, remove duplicates (aka spaces). Then apply filters/copy paste to get the desired format.